# handle multiple rows in a BEFORE INSERT trigger when inserting multiple rows through single SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, triggers

I have **USER** table which has "id" and "name" columns.there is **PRODUCT** table which has "id" and "user_id" columns."user_id" column has foreign key reference to "id" column in **USER** table.when I am inserting multiple rows using single sql query which has the same user_id.like

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT(id,user_id) VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1);
```

I want to execute before insert trigger for handle below conditions.

- on the PRODUCT table, get the number of rows which have same foreign key references as the inserting records' foreign key.
- if above number greater than or equal to three.allow to insert the all the rows.
- if the above number is 0 and the number of raws which are trying to insert is greater than or equal to three then allow to insert all the raws.
- if the above number is 0 and the number of raws which are trying to insert is less than to three then don't allow to insert all the raws and send an error message.

can anyone help me to write the BEFORE INSERT trigger to handle all of those conditions?

Comment: It looks like the only thing to want to stop is when there is only 1 or 2 existing related products. Everything else you allow through. Is that correct?

Comment: yes.@KeithJohnHutchison..please can you help me with that.

Comment: Please add schema commands and populate that schema with some sample data to your question.

Comment: Not possible in mysql because mysql triggers deal with inserts on a row by row basis and cannot now about all the inserts in a multi row insert. Not possible in sql server because sql server does not have a before insert trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use left join and count on existing entries to achieve only inserting entries when there is either 3 or more records already stored or the insert has at least three records to insert for a user id.

```
    CREATE TABLE if not exists `product_46353892` (
      `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    /* 
        truncate table to allow rerun of example 
        */
    truncate product_46353892 ;

    /* 
        example showing no inserts since there are only two records being inserted 
        and no previous records for this user_id
        */
    insert into product_46353892 ( id, user_id )
    select `new`.*
    -- , new_count.count new_count
    -- , old.count old_count
    from (
        select 1 id, 1 user_id
        union all
        select 2 id, 1 user_id
    ) `new`
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from (
            select 1 id, 1 user_id
            union all
            select 2 id, 1 user_id
        ) new_group
        group by user_id
    ) new_count
    on `new`.user_id = new_count.user_id
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from product_46353892 product
        group by user_id
    ) old
    on new.user_id = old.user_id
    where ( new_count.count >= 3 or old.count >= 3 or ( new_count.count + old.count ) >= 3 ) ;


    /* 
        this one works because there are three or more records in the insert
        */
    insert into product_46353892 ( id, user_id )
    select `new`.*
    from (
        select 3 id, 1 user_id
        union all
        select 4 id, 1 user_id
        union all 
        select 5 id, 1 user_id 
        union all 
        select 6 id, 1 user_id
    ) `new`
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from (
            select 3 id, 1 user_id
            union all
            select 4 id, 1 user_id
            union all 
            select 5 id, 1 user_id 
            union all 
            select 6 id, 1 user_id
        ) new_group
        group by user_id
    ) new_count
    on `new`.user_id = new_count.user_id
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from product_46353892 product
        group by user_id
    ) old
    on new.user_id = old.user_id
    where ( new_count.count >= 3 or old.count >= 3 or ( new_count.count + old.count ) >= 3 ) ;


    /* 
        this now works since there are already the required number of initial records stored 
        for this user_id
        */
    insert into product_46353892 ( id, user_id )
    select `new`.*
    -- , new_count.count new_count
    -- , old.count old_count
    from (
        select 1 id, 1 user_id
        union all
        select 2 id, 1 user_id
    ) `new`
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from (
            select 1 id, 1 user_id
            union all
            select 2 id, 1 user_id
        ) new_group
        group by user_id
    ) new_count
    on `new`.user_id = new_count.user_id
    left join (
        select user_id, count(*) count from product_46353892 product
        group by user_id
    ) old
    on new.user_id = old.user_id
    where ( new_count.count >= 3 or old.count >= 3 or ( new_count.count + old.count ) >= 3 ) ;


    select * from product_46353892 ;
```

Example results. Note the order of the id's, 1 and 2 was inserted on the second insert after there was already three or more records for the user id in the table.

```
id  user_id
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
1   1
2   1
```

Comment: first time user should buy at least three product.after that.user can buy any number of products as he wants.

Comment: Changed the logic to check for 3 or more existing or being inserted.